# removing images with specific size using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, delete-file

i have a folder with lots of jpg images. and i need to delete all the pictures which have size les than 160*160.i tried couple of codes in python my self. but they didn't work and i don't know what to do about it.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
folder_images = "dataset/PetImages/Cat"
for filenames in os.walk(folder_images):
    img = Image.open(filenames)
    h, w = img.shape
    if(not (h >= 160 or w >= 160)):
        os.remove(img)
```

here is the error i get:

> ```
> fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Your indentation is off. You need to indent everything that comes after your for loop.

Comment: @haidousm yes it was a mistake. but i guess the code is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that `Image.open()` returns an `Image` object, but `os.remove()` needs the `path` of file, not an `Image` object.

So here `img` should be replaced by `filenames` or something indicating the path of image.

Maybe you should read the documents carefully:

1. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open
2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove

By the way, an `PIL.image` object do not has `shape` attribute, what you need is `size`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open a list of images instead of just 1 image. Moreover, `os.remove(img)` is not correct since `img` is a PIL.image object instead of a filepath as @Sinon has mentioned already. Try this instead:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
folder_images = "dataset/PetImages/Cat"
for _, _, image_filenames in os.walk(folder_images):
    for image_filename in image_filenames:
        
        img = Image.open(image_filename)
        h, w = img.size
        if(not (h >= 160 or w >= 160)):
           os.remove(image_filename)
```